# Creating more rabbit consumers increases latency

Tags: php, rabbitmq, fpm

I have a server with a symfony app running on it as a rabbit-consumer(rpc to be precise). If I start one php-consumer, the latencies are about 300-500ms. If I start 2 or more consumers, the latency doubles to 600-1000ms when I add another consumer, and just keeps rising when I add more consumers into the mix. Overall throughput is improved a bit with the additional consumers, but why does the latencies go crazy like that? Latencies over 500ms are not cool..

The lonely application is not using even a percentage of the servers capacity, and I would like to utilize it better by starting a ton of rabbit consumers, but the latency...

I'm running:

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS trusty
- PHP7.1-fpm
- Nginx 1.4.6

I've read the whole internet, tried different configs(a lot of different configs), and debugged the sht out of this but I just cannot find out why it's doing this.

I'm not even sure what configs to offer here, so please ask them as needed.